# Calculating number of days in a month Based on leap year?

Tags: java

I need help making a program that takes the user input of a year and month (Ex. 2012 3) and outputs the number of days in it, BUT, it has to do so by determining whether it is a leap year or not  so that it can tell how many days the months have, so it cannot be pre-programmed, it must calculate on its own. AND it must prompt to re-input when an invalid month is entered (1-12 only) or negative integers/decimals are input. I have no clue how to start this!

I did start else i would not have asked,

System.out.println("Enter year and month: ");

```
    if (stdin.hasNextInt()) {
         yes = true;
    int year =  stdin.nextInt();
    int month = stdin.nextInt();
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. ");}

    if (yes = true);

    }
}
```

I dont know how to get it to take in the two numbers as separate INTs (2012 3) and how to reject month if its invalid or year if its invalid....

Comment: I recommend getting started on your assignment, and when you come across a concise, specific issue, ask about it on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you must check for to tell if a year is a leap year:

1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4 but not divisible by 100 then it is a leap year.
2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100 and also evenly divisible by 400 then it is a leap year.

-Code it uppppp

(also just google that ish next time-->"how to tell if a year is a leap year")

Answer (score 1):

Let's write a function that takes the year and month (1..12) number and returns the number of days in the given month

public int numberOfDays (int year, int month) {

Most month have a fixed number of days every year, so:

```
if (month==1||month==3||month==5||month==7||
    month==8||month==10||month==12) return 31;
if (month==4||month==6||month==9||month==11) return 30;
```

At this point (if the function hasn't returned), the month is either February, or it is an invalid month. Let's return an obviously invalid value if the month is invalid:

```
if (month!=2) return -1;
```

Now it becomes interesting, because February has 29 days on leap years and 28 days otherwise. Since the introduction of the Gregorian calendar in 1582 a leaps year is defined as a year that is multiple of 4, but years multiple of 100 are not leap years unless they are also multiple of 400 (i.e. 1600, 2000 and 2004 are leap years; 1900 and 2003 are not).

```
if (year>1582) {
 if (month%4==0&&(month%100!=0||month%400==0)) return 29; else return 28;
}
```

Before 1582, the Julian calendar was in force. Under the Julian calendar, every year divisible by 4 was a leap year.

```
else {
 //julian calendar
 if (month%4==0) return 29; else return 28;
}
```

Now the code calling `numberOfDays`:

```
int days;
do {
 System.out.println("blah blah blah");
 int year  =  stdin.nextInt();
 int month = stdin.nextInt();
 days  =  numberOfDays(year,month);
} while (days<0);
```